# Android - DateTimePicker

Tags: android, eclipse, datetimepicker

im quite new to android programming. Im am trying to make use of google's latest datetimepicker function. I downloaded the source code from https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/datetimepicker/+/e91a5dcdcc786074be1f6a9f2a4d79b99e34e18e and i imported it into my own project. So far i dont have any errors but i dont know how to make use of this function and test it into my project. I want to have a dialog box that will provide to the user the ability to select hours and minutes and a button click will save these data into my application.

Example: https://scontent-b-lhr.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ash3/t1.0-9/10157365_10203642451081150_8056765662416057326_n.jpg

Answer (score 0):

The Calendar app has the code to call the DatePickerDialog in the EditEventFragment (I think)

it looks about like this:

```
private class DateListener implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
    View mView;

    public DateListener(View view) {
        mView = view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePickerDialog view, int year, int month, int monthDay) {
        // Cache the member variables locally to avoid inner class overhead.
        Time startTime = mStartTime;
        Time endTime = mEndTime;

        // Cache the start and end millis so that we limit the number
        // of calls to normalize() and toMillis(), which are fairly
        // expensive.
        long startMillis;
        long endMillis;
        if (mView == mFromDateButton) {

            startTime.year = year;
            startTime.month = month;
            startTime.monthDay = monthDay;
            startMillis = startTime.normalize(true);
            setDate(mFromDateButton, startMillis);

        } else {
            endTime.year = year;
            endTime.month = month;
            endTime.monthDay = monthDay;
            // Do not allow an event to have an end time before the start
            // time.
            if (endTime.before(mStartTime)) {
                endTime.set(mStartTime);
            }
            endMillis = endTime.normalize(true);
            setDate(mToDateButton, endMillis);
        }

    }
}

private DatePickerDialog mDatePickerDialog;
private class DateClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
    private Time mTime;

    public DateClickListener(Time time) {
        mTime = time;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        final DateListener listener = new DateListener(v);
        if (mDatePickerDialog != null) {
            mDatePickerDialog.dismiss();
        }
        mDatePickerDialog = DatePickerDialog.newInstance(listener,
                mTime.year, mTime.month, mTime.monthDay);
         mDatePickerDialog.setFirstDayOfWeek(PickerUtils.getFirstDayOfWeekAsCalendar( getActivity()));
        mDateRangePickerDialog.setYearRange(mToday.year, mToday.year + 2);
        mDateRangePickerDialog.show(getActivity().getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
    }
}
```